# validate dynamic radiobutton div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create the dynamic table row with radio button and button.If I click add control button the row will create dynamically.the radio button id is **radiodiv**

I need to highlight the radio button's div, if the radio button options are not selected.

It was working for the first row of the table rest of others it was not working.

now I need ,If I press validate controls button ,need to highlight the radiobutton's div in each row.How to do this?

```
 $("#inputId").click(function () {
            var table = $('table#mytable');
            var row = "<tr><td> <div id='radiodiv'> <input type='radio' name='sex' value='male'>Male<br><input type='radio' name='sex' value='female'>Female</td></div>*" +
                                    "<td> <input type='button' id='btnAdd'  value='ValidateControls' /> </td>";
            var col = $('<td style="width:100px;" align="left"></td>');
            $('#tableview').append(table.append(row));                

        });


        //radio button check or not
        $('#mytable').on('click', '#btnAdd', function () {
            $(this).parents('tr').find('input:radio').each(function () {
                if($("input:radio[name='sex']").is(":checked"))
                    $("#radiodiv").css('border', '')
                else
                    $("#radiodiv").css('border', '1px solid red')
            });
        });
```

Refer the following Fiddle:[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6aBEf/8/)

Comment: `name` attribute is for grouping, you need to set separate name at the time of appending radio buttons. And `ID`s also must be **unique**!

Comment: You need to change the ID to a name or a class - ID must be unique  $('#mytable').on('click', `'.btnAdd'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems:

1. IDs must be unique per page, so radiodiv and btnAdd should both be classes.
2. You need a reference to the appropriate radiodiv from the context of the button pressed.

I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6aBEf/9/

Here are the changes:

```
$("#inputId").click(function () {
    var table = $('table#mytable');
    var row = "<tr><td> <div class='radiodiv'> <input type='radio' name='sex' value='male'>Male<br><input type='radio' name='sex' value='female'>Female</td></div>*" +
                            "<td> <input type='button' class='btnAdd'  value='ValidateControls' /> </td>";
    var col = $('<td style="width:100px;" align="left"></td>');
    $('#tableview').append(table.append(row));                
});


//radio button check or not
$('#mytable').on('click', '.btnAdd', function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('input:radio').each(function () {
        if($("input:radio[name='sex']").is(":checked"))
            $(this).closest(".radiodiv").css('border', '')
        else
            $(this).closest(".radiodiv").css('border', '1px solid red')
    });
});
```

Comment: Not super elegant and you have not addressed the illegal html

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the ID to a name or a class - ID must be unique

Also your html is illegal - and what is `col` used for?

Here is a more elegant solution than the each

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/RxVMD/)

```
<table >
  <tbody id="mytable"></tbody>
</table>
```

using

```
$("#inputId").click(function () {
   var row = "<tr><td> <div class='radiodiv'> <input type='radio' name='sex' value='male'>Male<br><input type='radio' name='sex' value='female'>Female</div>*</td>" +
             "<td> <input type='button' class='btnAdd'  value='ValidateControls' /> </td></tr>";
   $('#mytable').append(row);                
});
//radio button check or not
$('#mytable').on('click', '.btnAdd', function () {
    var $div = $(this).closest("tr").find('.radiodiv');
    $check = $div.find("input:radio[name='sex']:checked").length;
    $div.css('border',$check==0?'1px solid red':"");
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6aBEf/10/ I update as per your comments..still its not working.If I press any validatecontrol button.It will affect first row of the table alone

Comment: @User Care to check my update from much earlier today?